# Classify the singularities of the function .

Tags: complex-analysis

Classify the singularities of the function

$\frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^2(z-1)}$.

I think my answer may be that I have a simple pole at $z=0$ and a removable singularitie at $z=-1$ however i am not too sure. Some help, appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't it be a simple pole at $z=1$ and removable singularity at $z=0$?

Comment: A simple pole and a removable singularity at z=0 and a simple pole at z=1 rather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose the $\cos(z)$ into a Teylor series and you'll see that $z^2$ goes away (removable singularity):

$$1 - \cos(z) = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - ...\right) = \frac{z^2}{2!} - \frac{z^4}{4!} + \frac{z^6}{6!} ...$$

Now, you get: $$\frac{1 - \cos(z)}{z^2} = \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{z^2}{4!} + \frac{z^4}{6!} - \frac{z^6}{8!} + ...$$
And you see that this function doesn't have any singularities, so $z = 0$ is a removable singularity.

On contrary, $z-1$ will probably stay, so you have a simple pole at $z = 1$.